# Could this SQL query be made more efficient?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a very large table of **nodes** (cardinality of about 600,000), each record in this table can have one or more types associated with it. There is a **node_types** table that contains these (30 or so) type definitions.

To connect the two, I have a third table called **node_type_relations** that simply links node ids to type ids.

I am trying to clean up orphaned node_type_relation entries after a cull of the node table. My query to delete any type relations for which the node no longer exists is;

```
DELETE FROM node_type_relations WHERE node_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM nodes)
```

But judging by the speed at which this is running (one record being deleted per 10 seconds or so), it looks like Postgres is loading up the entire nodes table once for every record in the node_type_relations table (which is about 1.4million records in size).

I was about to dive in and write some code to do it more sensibly when I thought I'd ask here if the query could be turned inside-out somehow. Anything to avoid loading the nodes table more than once.

Thanks as always.

---

**Edit with solution**

Executing the query;

```
DELETE FROM node_type_relations WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM nodes WHERE nodes.id=node_type_relations.node_id)
```

appears to have had the desired effect and deleted all orphaned records (some 170,000) in a matter of seconds.

Comment: what about indexing nodes.id and node_type_relations.node_id?

Comment: YOu should define a `ON DELETE CASCADE` to avoid running a cleanup in the future.

Comment: Have you looked at the EXPLAIN output?

Comment: @ sebas - both are indexed, that was my first thought when I realised how slow it was running. @ juergen d - I will certainly look into that, I assume I have to tell postgres that the two tables are linked in some way? @ jonathan leffler - I am not familiar with postgres so much, I will google that now.

Comment: How fast does the query run when you replace `DELETE FROM` with `SELECT id FROM`?

Comment: I would left join `node_type_relations` to `nodes` and (psuedo) `DELETE WHERE nodes.id IS NULL`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - it appears to be equally slow

Comment: If the SELECT is running equally slowly, there is probably a problem with the indexes and the query plan from EXPLAIN should indicate what it is doing.  The DELETE will (most probably) be analogous.  At a speed of 1 record per 10 seconds, you can afford to extract the data from the DB, munge it using Unix tools, and then drop the data and reload; it would be quicker.  So, something is seriously amiss.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - I will look into EXPLAIN, thanks for the tip. Check my edit in the answer above, it ran puzzlingly quickly. So quickly in fact that i am now carefully checking over the data...

Comment: @lynks: sometimes a correlated subquery is exactly what you need.

Comment: If the id keys are both NOT NULLable, the queries are equivalent, and should result in the same query plan. The "LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL" query by SeanW below is equivalent to the "NOT EXISTS(...)" form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@lynks' found the optimal query for his case himself - with an `EXISTS` semi-join:

```
DELETE FROM node_type_relations ntr
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   nodes n
   WHERE  n.id = ntr.node_id
   );
```

A solution with JOIN syntax would have to be constructed like this in PostgreSQL:

```
DELETE FROM node_type_relations d
USING  node_type_relations ntr
LEFT   JOIN nodes n ON n.id = ntr.node_id
WHERE  ntr.node_id = d.node_id
AND    n.id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe do a left join, and then delete where null.

So:

```
 DELETE ntr
 FROM node_type_relations ntr
 LEFT JOIN nodes n
 ON n.id = ntr.node_id
 WHERE n.id IS NULL
```

Comment: you could also use: "delete top (50) ntr" to just do a few at a time

Comment: postgres doesn't appear to like your syntax, but i can probably figure it out from here, thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, that was TSQL for SQL Server. I should have mentioned you'd need to adapt it.

Comment: despite my solution being of a different structure, ill keep yours as the chosen answer, as it led me to discover the final solution.

Comment: @lynks: The question is clearly tagged [PostgreSQL]. This answer is just wrong. You should not accept it, that's misleading to others. It's also bad style to edit the right answer into your question. Please post your correct answer and accept. [Those are the customs here!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16930/is-it-ok-to-answer-your-own-question-and-accept-it) I posted a community wiki with the correct answer. If you found this useful, you can still upvote ...